# Is it possible to disable USB Power output?

Tags: usb, windows-10

I have a USB-Powered fan that I attached to my computer. However, if I'm just watching videos or doing basic word processing, my computer doesn't need this fan to be enabled and cold air is blown on my leg.

I want to completely disable a specific USB port's power output and re-enable it on-demand. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get a [switchable USB hub](https://www.google.com/search?q=switchable%20usb%20hub&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8). This will let you power off everything on it at once but it'll only use a single port.

Comment: If possible I'd like to a) not buy any hardware and b) be able to switch it off using software (windows)

Comment: I don't think so but maybe someone will know how. The reason I doubt that this is possible is because the fan only uses the power wires in the USB cable and I think that this power can only be disabled by completely disabling the USB controller in the BIOS. Meaning you'd need to reboot.

Comment: If you would allow hardware, I could show you how to build what you want using a micro controller.

Comment: If I have a raspberry pi could I use that?

Comment: Yes, but I'm not familiar with using that as a micro controller. You might try asking about that on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ you will also need a few components as well.